# JavaScript fails on mobile-safari when web-inspector is switched off

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, web-inspector

I have a script using socket.io which fails whenever web-inspector is switched off and the phone is not connected to a safari on a Mac.

Unfortunately this means that I cannot identify the problem and am unable to provide the relevant part of the source code.

My question is, does the execution of JavaScript in mobile-safari vary in any way when web-inspector is switched on and the phone is connected to a Mac Safari console?

Answer (score 1):

Execution does not differ whether Web Inspector is enabled or disabled. If Web Inspector is disabled, then calls to `console.log` and friends are simply ignored and not shown anywhere. Similarly, the `debugger` statement will have no effect if a debugger (i.e., local or remote Web Inspector) is not attached.

If you believe execution does differ in this case, then that is a bug in Safari or Web Inspector. Please [file bug reports!](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem case with disabled web-inspector occurs in the presence of commands in the code:

```
console.log();
console.info();
console.error();
```

It can easily be checked temporarily comment out the calls of these functions if they are available in your code.